# Задание точности для вещественной величины в phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, веб-программирование, mysql

Есть база данных book_sc и в ней таблица:

```
create database book_sc;
create table orders
(
orderid int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
customerid int unsigned not null,
amount float(6,2),
date date not null,
order_status char(10),
ship_name char(40) not null,
ship_address char(40) not null,
ship_city char(20) not null,
ship_state char(20),
ship_zip char(10),
ship_country char(20) not null
) ;
```

Как задать точность для поля amount после создания таблицы? (я уже создал, но есть же возможность редактирования, так вот как задать точность (6,2))?

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html